# Maintaining multiple builds for different compiler versions

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I am developing a C++ library and I use a Makefile to compile and create a build. I wish to maintain multiple builds for different gcc compiler versions. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What differences do you want between builds, other than versions of the compiler?

Comment: @Beta No other differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to go with autotools, autoconf/automake let you do this through [out of tree builds](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/VPATH-Builds.html). You can configure as many build you want if you separate each build into its own directory (not the source directory).

Configuring compiler and compiler options is usually a simple matter of bash command line.

```
mkdir mingw-build
cd mingw-build
CXX=mingw32-g++ ../myproject/configure ...
cd ..

mkdir native-build
cd native-build
CXX=g++ ../myproject/configure ...
cd ..
```

Comment: or go one better with CMake - maintains multiple compilers against multiple targets easily.

Comment: @RichardHodges autotools are frontends to `make`. `cmake` is a replacement to `make`. As the OP ask about `make` I think my answer is relevant.

Comment: I totally agree that your answer is relevant. 
CMake also has generators for `Makefiles`. In general, I find it an easier and more flexible solution than autotools.

Comment: @RichardHodges how do I do it with cmake?

Comment: @RichardHodges My aim is to maintain multiple .so files simultaneously for a few compiler versions and check in all of the .so files into the repository. Will cmake/autotools serve the purpose?

Comment: checking in an object file is usually frowned upon, but you must do what you feel is right. CMake uses "out of source" builds, which means that each variation is built in its own directory but uses the same source code. This allows you to maintains all your build versions of the code at once.